# User Log Out displaying in all the users

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Im trying to create a member page but when im logged in as the user
i need a log out button and if im logged in as the (X) user and i try to access (Y) user's profile i still get the logout button. Basically, im trying to get a logout button only when im logged in as my user and if i want to check another profile i want to check it and dont want a logout button to show on another profile page while im logged in.

**PROFILE.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once 'php/classes/class.user.php';

//echo 'GET:'; 
//var_dump($_GET); 
//echo '$_SESSION:'; 
//echo var_dump($_SESSION); 

$user = new User();

$uid = $_GET['uid'];

if(isset($_SESSION['uid']) && $_GET['uid'] == $_SESSION['uid']){

    if ($user->check_user($uid)) {

        echo " " . $user->get_fullname($uid) . " ";
        echo "<a href='profile.php?q=logout'>Log Out</a>";

    }

}else if(isset($_SESSION['uid']) && $_GET['uid'] != $_SESSION['uid']){

    echo " " . $user->get_fullname($uid) . " ";

}else if(!isset($_SESSION['uid']) && $_GET['uid'] != $_SESSION['uid']){
    echo " " . $user->get_fullname($uid) . " ";
}else if($user->check_user($count_row1) > $uid){
    echo "User Doesn't exist";
}

if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $user->user_logout();
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

**USERS.FUNCTIONS.php**

```
<?php 
include "db_config.php";

class User{

    public $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
                exit;
        }
    }

    /*** for login process ***/
    public function check_login($emailusername, $password){

        $password = md5($password);
        $sql2="SELECT uid from users WHERE uemail='$emailusername' or uname='$emailusername' and upass='$password'";

        //checking if the username is available in the table
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql2);
        $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $count_row = $result->num_rows;

        if ($count_row == 1) {
            // this login var will use for the session thing    
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = true;
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $user_data['uid'];
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    /*** for showing the username or fullname ***/

    public function get_fullname($uid){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql);
    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        echo $user_data['fullname'], "<br/>";
        echo $user_data['uemail'], "<br/>";
        echo $user_data['uid'], "<br/>";
    }

    public function check_user($uid){

    $sql5 = "SELECT uid from users WHERE uid='$uid'";
    $result1 = $this->db->query($sql5);
    $count_row1 = $result1->num_rows;

    return ($count_row1 ==1);


    }

    /*** starting the session ***/
    public function get_session(){
        return $_SESSION['login'];
    }

    public function user_logout() {
        $_SESSION['login'] = FALSE;
        session_destroy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code

```
if (isset($_GET['uid'])) {
// Your Code of Check user exist? I don't get it
}
else if (isset($_SESSION['uid'], $_SESSION['login'])) {
// Your Code to print Logout
}
else
echo "Session not set";
```

This actually doesn't make sense, You are checking `uid` first. I'm guessing that's user's unique id.  If  `uid` is set, it won't even go to else part. And if I ignore that in your else part you are not checking whether current user is the same user who is logged in, you should do something like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'],$_GET['uid']))
 {
   if($_GET['uid']==$_SESSION['uid'])
    {
     //Your Code to Print Logout
    }
  else if($user->check_user($uid))
   {
    //User Exist and Not Logged in User
   }
  else if(!$user->check_user($uid))
   {
   //User Doesn't Exist
   }
 }
```

You must use a GET parameter to check current profile with your logged in user. I advise you to eliminate first `if` condition and use above condition.

Edit : As you want to print if user exist or not, there can be multiple ways, I just edited to show an example, but it can be different according to multiple circumstances. **It is just an idea**

Comment: Kind of helped. But now i cant seem tog et the error when an user doesnt exist. mind looking at the updated code?\

Comment: Actually if user doesn't exist, how will he log in?

Comment: I as the user am logged in. but lets say i search for an id thats not on the db, it should give me an error that that user profile doesn't exist . EX (only 2 user profiles on DB) id=1, id=2, if i type id=3(error, user doesn't exist)

Comment: EDIT> WORKING @Prateek. But how can i get an error message only on the profile.php(without the id) page

Comment: This will work only when `uid` and `session` variables are set. try to check using `echo` if conditions are being executed or not?

Comment: Managed to fix @prateek. Thanks brother really. Just changed couple of things.  if(isset($_SESSION['uid'],$_GET['uid'])){
 
  if($_GET['uid']==$_SESSION['uid']){
  
   if ($user->check_user($uid)) {
    echo " " . $user->get_fullname($uid) . " ";
    echo "<a href='profile.php?q=logout'>Log Out</a>";
   }
   
  }else if($user->check_user($uid)){
  
   echo " " . $user->get_fullname($uid) . " ";
   
    }else if(!$user->check_user($uid)){
    
   echo "User doesn't exist";
   
    }
 }else{
  echo "Can't access";
 } my working code

Answer (score 0):

I think you use this class to create all the profile page of all the user.

For don't show the logout button when you visit the profile of another user you have some solution:

1) create a different php file to show the other user profile;
2) control if the user id registered in the session is the same of the profile you want to show,if not,dont' show the button

When a user log in you store in session this:

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = $user_data['uid'];
```

Now, you have the ID of the CURRENT user logged, need the id of the user you want to show the personal page. I think in your database the id of the user is unique or primary key with auto increment.

Example, X logged in and want to see the personal page of the user Y.

In $_SESSION['uid'] you have stored the id of the user X.
When a user click over a link to see the personal page of Y,you have to retrieve with a query the uid of the user Y.

HTML PAGE EXAMPLE

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="personal_page.php?var=usernameY> Y </a>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP PAGE EXAMPLE

```
<?php
$username_Y = $_REQUEST['var'];
$query = "SELECT uid FROM table WHERE username = $username_Y";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $user_Y_id = $row['uid'];
}

    if($_SESSION['uid'] != $user_Y_id) {
      //show button
    } else {
      // don't show button but other you want
    }
?>
```